# C++ Pointer by Reference, lists of classes and Pointers, wierd return

Tags: c++, list, pointers, return-by-reference

I've got a program, that stores sets of classes and structs in lists.

It does the following:

1. Passes an input (an `int`), an iterator, a list and a pointer by reference into the function `check()`
2. Iterates the list until it finds a match between the iterator's data and the input
3. Sets the pointer as the iterator's position
4. Returns true or false, depending on whether a match was found or not.

My problem is, when I call the function `display()` from within the function check, whether it be from `it->display()`, or `Ptr->display()`, it works fine. But when it's passed back out by reference, and I try to display it. It prints garbage.

```
//it is the iterator, l is the list, Ptr is the passed pointer
template<class T, class T2, class P>
bool Inspection::check(int input, T it, T2 l, P * &Ptr)
{
    for(it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); ++it){   //Iterates through list using iterator
        if (it->checkExists(input)){        //if input == iterator class's data
            Ptr = &*it;

            //Display data - ERROR CHECKING//
            it->display();          
            Ptr->display();

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`checkExists` is a function that compares to the private data in the class it's iterating, Such as

```
bool Property::checkExists(int input)
{
    if (input == ID)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

`display` is also straightforward

```
void Property::display()
{
    //Prints out property info
    cout << ID << ";" << address << ";" << landTypes[type] << ";" << price << endl;
}
```

A standard call is (`p` is a list of the `Property` classes that I've called earlier in the program)

```
int input;
Property * temp; //Pointer to a class temp
list<Property>::iterator pIT;

cin >> input;


while(!check(input, pIT, p, temp)){
    ...
}
    temp->display();
```

A typical output would be (First two are calls within the function and correct, the third is the `temp->display();` call from outside the function.

```
1001;5/10 Northfields Ave, North Wollongong, NSW 2500;Townhouse;280000
1001;5/10 Northfields Ave, North Wollongong, NSW 2500;Townhouse;280000
13;�������\314���@�ve, North Wollongong, NSW 2500;Townhouse;280000
```

EDIT: Sorry I linked the wrong display function(). Edited code to update

Comment: Where is it being passed out by reference?

Comment: bool Inspection::check(int input, T it, T2 l, P * &Ptr)

In the first codeblock, Where Ptr is being pushed into the function, and back out again

Comment: And what is `p` that you passed to the function call?

Comment: p is the list of classes that pIT is iterating through

Comment: That entire premise of passing the list and a by-val uninitialized iterator you're subsequently just using as a local variable needs to be completely redone. Forget passing the list. Pass two iterators (the begin and the end) by-val, and possibly use `iterator_traits<It>` to get attributes of the underlying data type, to be used as the return type. In other words, you're making this far more complicated that it needs to be. As a bonus, using two iterators allows you to swap your container with utter impunity.

Comment: Thanks dude! 

This is the first time I've worked with lists (just going into second year ComSci at Uni), and am trying to familiarise myself with dynamic data types outside of building my own linked list. Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not withstanding the design issues pointed out by WhozCraig the issue with printing out garbage in the code you provided is as follows:

```
 template<class T, class T2, class P>
 bool Inspection::check(int input, T it, T2 l, P * &Ptr)
                                         ^^^^
```

You are passing `l` by value instead of by reference, so you are getting back a pointer to a temporary variable which won't exist when you dereference it outside of the method. If you modify the code as following it should start working for this particular issue although it really does need a redesign:

```
template<class T, class T2, class P>
bool Inspection::check(int input, T it, T2 &l, P * &Ptr)
```

Comment: Thankyou! That did fix it, but I agree, I will definitely go back and attempt to rewrite it. Your help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: @RoryChatterton Very glad it worked. A sample of what I was referring to can be found [at this link](http://ideone.com/NoZafi). It could be made significantly better, including using SFINAE to ensure the base type of the data being iterated is a Property or Property-derivative, but as-is I hope it provides something to think about. Again, glad you're up and running. (and +1 to the answer).